# NodeJS: Possible to host an HTTPS server without a domain name (hobby project)

Tags: node.js, express, https

I'm making a hobby project and it involves a NodeJS http server that I access via a web browser (through GET and POST requests). The HTML/CSS/JS part of the webpage is local, not on the NodeJS server.

I understand I need to generate SSL certificates but those ask for things like domain names and stuff.

I simply want to enable HTTPS on my NodeJS server. Right now I'm manually encrypting all messages sent back and forth through AES, but I trust the https security more, I'm not a cryptographer.

Is there an easy way to get those certificates? My NodeJS server is accessible via the internet but only by IP address (port forwarded), and through the express module using HTTP requests.

Do I need to pay for them?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can take services from [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/), you can buy subscription as per your choice and deploy your Nodejs app with free SSL certificate.(let's encrypt)

However I recommend you to understand following concepts

- Reverse proxy (nginx)
- Process managements (pm2)
- SSL certificates

I am sure, You would love to go though with starter tutorials from DigitalOcean

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-20-04
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04
- [https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04)

As Its a hobby project, otherwise I would have recommended other options.

Comment: What other options would you recommend? Is using regular http while encrypting all the messages myself using AES a good option?

Comment: you can use heroku cloud, its free.